# Not able to center multple Div tags on this website

Tags: html, css, centering

I've been trying for two days to get these div items to center horizontally. I have multiple logos that need to go on two lines. They seem to not want to center but want to float left. I can't figure out what is making it do so.

```css
.partners_section_container {
  display: table;
  height: 65px;
  text-align: center;
}

.x-content-band {
  margin: 0 0 0.15em;
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.x-container.max.width.wpb_row {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.partner_logos {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.partner_logo1 {
  padding: 15px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 14%;
}
```

```html
<div id="x-content-band-4" class="x-content-band vc partners_section_container" style="background-color: transparent; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
  <div class="x-container max width wpb_row">
    <div class="x-column x-sm vc  partner_logos x-1-1" style="">
      <div class="partner_logo1"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-62" src="http://leadershipwv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Argos.jpg" alt="argos logo" width="206" height="86" data-pin-nopin="true"></div>
      <div class="partner_logo1"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-57" src="http://leadershipwv.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/BBT.png" alt="BB&amp;T logo" width="150" height="60" data-pin-nopin="true"></div>
      <div class="partner_logo1"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-58" src="http://leadershipwv.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/brickstreet.png" alt="brickstreet logo" width="198" height="84" data-pin-nopin="true"></div>
      <div class="partner_logo1"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-59" src="http://leadershipwv.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/dominion.png" alt="dominion logo" width="198" height="94"></div>
      <div class="partner_logo1"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-62" src="http://leadershipwv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/DOWdiamond.gif" alt="dow logo" width="206" height="86"></div>
      <div class="partner_logo1"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-62" src="http://leadershipwv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/EQT.jpg" alt="eqt logo" width="206" height="86"></div>
      <div class="partner_logo1"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-62" src="http://leadershipwv.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/firstenergy.png" alt="first energy logo" width="206" height="86"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you would like to see the live site, [please view it here.](http://www.leadershipwv.org/)

Comment: Thanks #jack, I didn't know how to set up that snippet thing!

Comment: What's not centered about it? I see a bunch of logos spaced evenly horizontal.

Comment: I found out what it was. It was something with the wordpress theme! I added this and it seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you're using table-cell in 2017, I'll recommend you use flexbox, it will help you a lot.

If you want to center something in a container I'll do it easily like this:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto; }

  .logos {
  padding: 40px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; }

  .logo {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 14%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; }
```

Using flex-wrap in the logos class causes that when the content reaches the max width it automatically breaks to the next column using the same rules and proportions.

I use the box-sizing property in logo to ensure that the content will never exceed 14% width, if so this will cause a weird display in some cases.

Comment: Looks like I need to brush up on my CSS huh? Thanks for the tip Victor!

Answer (score 0):

So there apparently was something funky with the wordpress theme itself. I found it and added this code and it fixed the issue.

```
.x-container.max.width.wpb_row { max-width: 1600px!important;}
```